# How to run app from root url (localhost:port/) instead of (localhost:port/path/index.html)

Tags: intellij-idea, dart, webstorm

This is a problem that I have when I run/debug the app from Webstorm.

The run/debug configuration dialog doesn't give us much to work with, we can just specify the path of the index.html file there.

I wanna be able to set up a configuration similar to what [yeoman's angular generator](https://github.com/yeoman/generator-angular) gives us out of the box.

Comment: What do you mean with "run app"? When you launch it from DartEditor or when you deploy it to another server? Usually a Dart web app should run with any root path and the redirection to `index.html` (when the request URL doesn't contain a specific file) is part of the server which processes the request.

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer, sorry, I thought it was implicit based on the Webstorm tag. So this happens in dev mode, when I run/debug the app.

Comment: I see, didn't look at the tags...

Comment: I don't know of a solution but you are not alone ;-) https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-14047 What's the actual problem with the current behavior (I don't know what yeoman's angular generator does).

Comment: Yap, I totally agree with the guys there. As I'm digging into dart and webstorm, I feel like i'll trip over issues like bad assets references and client routing problems. Even the bundled dart template (Web Application) has this exact problem: You click a button in the app, you are in a new client route, that route is not accessible directly by typing it in the browser.

Comment: The way yeoman generated workflow deals with this problem, is that it starts a new server for each app. Where assets are being served from the root url (localhost:differentPortForEachApp/)

Answer (score 2):

WebStorm built-in web server serves the project from `'http://localhost:<built-in server port>/<project root>`'. If you like to change the default web path on built-in web server, you have to re-configure the server by editing your system hosts file accordingly - see http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-8988#comment=27-577559. But, as it's mentioned in [this comment](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-14047#comment=27-837762), there are currently some issues with serving dart apps on server configured this way.
Please follow [WEB-14047](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-14047) for updates